# NHibernate + Generated value (client side) for property on each update

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Basically I have a simple base class:

```
public abstract class BasePoco {

    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual DateTime Created { get; protected set; }
    public virtual DateTime LastModified { get; protected set; }
    public virtual User LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

}
```

With the following mapping:

```
<class name="BasePoco" abstract="true">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="Created" generated="insert" />
    <property name="LastModified" generated="always" />
    <many-to-one name="LastModifiedBy" />
</class>
```

The Created property is set via a database default value, the LastModified via a database trigger (haven't tested it yet, but I assume this will work). But how can I set the "LastModifiedBy" in a nice clean way? Instead of setting this property in my code every time I want to update a poco, I'd like to have something like a static method NHibernate can call on every update (and of course, this method will return the currently logged on user).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook to [events that fire before inserts and updates](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/creating-an-audit-log-using-nhibernate-events.aspx) in Nhibernate; you can add audit, autofill some fields, etc... [This Ayende post](http://ayende.com/blog/3987/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-ipreinserteventlistener) (very recommended) also covers the basics

I managed my createdDate/modifiedDate/createdBy fields this way, and also added audit so i could allow hard-deletions in the database while keeping information about what was deleted

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is the solution. I'll dig into it!